# Is one allowed to go to a funeral on moed?

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya, chol-hamoed

Is someone who is not a relative of the deceased allowed to go to the funeral on moed or is it forbidden because of אסור לעורר עצב ברגל? (One may not invoke sadness on a festival)

Comment: Where does this come from? אסור לעורר עצב ברגל? (Or אסור לערר עצב ברגל in your original)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch ([OC §526:6](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%95#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.95)) explicitly states:

> מותר ללוות המת ביום טוב ראשון תוך התחום וביום טוב שני אפילו חוץ לתחום

Trans.:

> It is permitted to accompany the deceased on the first day of the holiday within the [designated] domain; on the second day of the holiday it is permissible to accompany even beyond the domain.

AFAIK no persons are excluded from the above.

Answer (score 3):

Building off of @Danny's answer, it seems implicit from the Mishna in [Moed Katan 3:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Moed_Katan.3.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that it is permitted to do so (and appears that from there the law permitting attendance of funerals on Moed is derived):

(*Source(s) from [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/)*)

> אֵין קוֹרְעִין, וְלֹא חוֹלְצִין, וְאֵין מַבְרִין, אֶלָּא קְרוֹבָיו שֶׁל מֵת, וְאֵין מַבְרִין אֶלָּא עַל מִטָּה זְקוּפָה. אֵין מוֹלִיכִין לְבֵית הָאֵבֶל לֹא בְּטַבְלָא וְלֹא בְאִסְקוּטְלָא וְלֹא בְקָנוֹן, אֶלָּא בְסַלִּים. וְאֵין אוֹמְרִים בִּרְכַּת אֲבֵלִים בַּמּוֹעֵד, **אֲבָל עוֹמְדִין בְּשׁוּרָה וּמְנַחֲמִין וּפוֹטְרִין אֶת הָרַבִּים:**
>
> *We may not tear [our garments], nor lay bare [a shoulder], nor offer a funeral meal, except for the relatives of the dead. The funeral meal is only offered on an upright couch. We do not carry [the food] to the house of mourning: not on a tray, nor in a silver tureen, nor in a dish, but in baskets. We do not say the blessing of mourners during the intermediate days, **but we stand in a row<sup>1</sup>, comfort [the mourners] and then dismiss the masses**.*

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Additionally, the concept of שׁוּרָה (*standing in a row*) is explained in a Mishna in [Brachos 3:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.3.2?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en), that this occurred immediately after the burial</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There are Halachot of what one can & cannot do on Moed during a funeral, hence it is permitted. See [סימן ר - דין הקבורה ביום טוב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0199_L2) in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch for examples.

E.g.: Eulogies are forbidden.

One can even go to a funeral on Yom Tov, should there be one. (ibid)